# Check if form is called from correct page

Tags: php, forms

On page1.php I have a form which sends vars via POST to page2.php. 
However, I only want to process the form if it is called from page1.php.

How do I check for this?

Kind regards!

EDIT:
It's a kind of security measure. If i'm a hacker and I copy the form code from the source of the page and run it, I can change crucial vars.

**EDIT2:** 
Ok here is the actual problem: 
Users can edit credit to their account. They can choose values from 5EUR to 50EUR.
Eventually they come on a page 'deposit.php' where the final form is sent to a page 'payments.php' which then sends the var to Paypal.

Deposit.php:

```
<form class="paypal" action="paypal/payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank">    
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="BE" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="50" / >
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="47.50" / >
<input type="submit" class="uibutton " value="Betaal met Paypal" style="width: 100%; font-size:120%;">
```

(BTW they get a discount if they add 50EUR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all you have to understand that **there is no security measure** the way you put it. 
And, of course, **no method provided by other participants can protect your "crucial vars"**. They were actually answering other question, one is more familiar to them.

Forms are intended to be filled by client party. So, you can't expect whatever variable be untouched. **Everything** coming from the client side can be spoofed, no matter what measures you took.

So, whatever "crucial vars" should **remain on the server.**
While all the data coming from the form should be considered unsafe and treated accordingly.

Comment: How do I keep one particular var server-sided? I only now the 'form' way via GET or POST..

Comment: For us to help we need to understand the code you already have in place, or the security you're desiring.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the application, you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and do a check but the problem with it is that not all browsers send it, and it is modifiable by the user. So if this is just for a few people that you know it probably won't be a problem. If this is for the world it isn't recommended.

What I usually do is set a session on page 1, then check for that session on page 2. Every time page 1 loads you need to reset the session.

**page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$hash = $_SESSION['hash'] = md5(time().rand(0,100));
?>
<form action="page2.php" meethod="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="<?php echo $hash; ?>" />
    Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['hash'] != $_POST['h']){
    header("Location: page1.php");
    exit;
}

// process data
```

Comment: But for example:
I can pick a teddybear to buy which costs 50 euro.
The forms sends the name of the product and the price. I continue to page2 so a session is created. Meanwhile I open the same page1 I copied onto my localhost and run the script but I changed the price to 0euro. Now page2 detects the session ID from my first call, and I have to pay 0 euro.

I know I can check for the price but in my case that's not an option it's just an example.

Comment: This is the exact same solution as my example. Storing the session key as a hidden variable still allows the user to inspect the page, and modify as needed.

Comment: But yours you don't have a server with a secret key that the client needs to know. Yours, the client tells the server what the key is, and the server assumes it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think *Adam D* response is too weak (Anyone can change that just using firebug). what you want to prevent is users to skip some step or avoid [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

In that case I would say use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

- Create a session
- Save the current step
- Retrieve and validate the current step and halt or continue according to the value

Comment: Original poster never said that it needed to be ultimately secure; just said check that they came from `page1.php`

Comment: it doesn't matter. if you ask me how to smash meat I would say: _use a hammer and try to don't hurt yourself_ same here: _do it and do it secure_

Answer (score -2):

In your form, include a hidden field that you then check for on `page2.php`. See below:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cameFromPageOne" value="true" />
</form>
```

Then, on the top of `page2.php`, check that the hidden variable is set, and if not, redirect back to `page1.php`

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['cameFromPageOne']) || $_POST['cameFromPageOne'] != 'true') {
  header('location: http://www.example.com/page1.php');
  exit();
} else {
    // ... code to process if they DID come from page1.php
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast respond! I already thought of this, however, if I'm a hacker, I check the Source Code of the page and copy the form, change crucial hidden variables, and run it.

Comment: Or use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but both are easy to spoof. Don't use these as security measures. Consider adding CSRF tokens.

Comment: these validations are too easy to avoid

Comment: I could come from some other site, and as long as I passed `<input type="hidden" name="cameFromPageOne" value="true" />` It would be validated as true

Comment: You never said that it needed to be ultimately secure, you just said check that they came from `page1.php`

Answer (score -3):

There's no reason to overcomplicate it, there's a global variable in PHP which tell's you the url your current script was requested from:

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Comment: That is not at all secure from php.net: `The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.`